# Android switching from activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I am making an Android app that has the `MainActivity` in it's **onCreate** check if it has to download a file. The check happens in a **AsynchTask** class. 
I have a second activity `PrefsActivity` that launches a `Prefsfragment` for preferences.

Now when I come back from the `PrefsActivity`,  **onCreate** is issued again.
But the whole check doesn't have to happen again.

**Code leading to preferences**

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.preferences:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, PrefsActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Code for preferences**

```
public class PrefsActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new PrefsFragment()).commit();

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
}
```

Code for starting Asynchtask in MainActivity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    PropertiesManager.getUniqueInstance().loadProperties(PropertiesManager.PROPERTIES_FILE, this);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean auto_update = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("pref_autoUpdate", true);
    File downloadFile = getExternalFilesDir("media/" + Downloader.DOWNLOAD_FILE_NAME);

    if (auto_update || !downloadFile.exists()) {
        try {
            if (new Downloader(this).execute().get()) {
                receiveBroadcast(this);
            } else {
                schedule = Parser.getUniqueInstance().parse(this);
                ScheduleBuilder.getUniqueInstance().build(this, (DayBean) schedule.get(9));
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
        } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        schedule = Parser.getUniqueInstance().parse(this);
        ScheduleBuilder.getUniqueInstance().build(this, (DayBean) schedule.get(9));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see your point ? Be more clear

Comment: When you come back from other activity onResume() will be called, not onCreate()

Comment: onCreate can also be called if the initial activity has been recreated.

Comment: You see that `savedInstanceState` parameter? Google it and use it :)

Comment: You could save the status of "Download File" in a Shared Preference/SaveInstance bundle, and could use that to start the async-task. When the activity 1 is creating again, you could use the shared-pref/SavedInstance Bundle to avoid running the async-task again. Hope this is what you asked for.

Comment: put a boolean, to check for if its switching from another activity or just starting from scratch

Comment: Well the check for download queries a website and checks if it has to download a new schedule. Even though small in size it still has to send and receive data and it takes time. When I press the settings menu button and press up in action bar to go back to the main screen that will display the current downloaded schedule, the oncreate of the mainactivity is run again and the check for the download will happen again. What I want is when returning to the mainactivity a different method is executed, or even better it just goes to the way it was.

Answer (score 0):

In the first activity create the AsyncTask only if the `savedInstance` bundle is null. This means the activity is not recreated due to configuration changes or because the user navigates back to it (your case). Something like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        //instantiate the AsyncTask and execute it 
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't get to work. I created  onsavedinstancestate to put a boolean. and in oncreate if savedinstancestate == null init a Asynch. but seems like the savedinstancestate is always null.

Comment: It is null when you're first time launching the activity.

Comment: yes. but when i go to the preferences activity and go back by means of the up button in actionbar it still initiates the asynch

Comment: Post the code for starting the asynctask and I'll show you how to fix it.

Comment: ums how can i reply. when i paste the code it says to long. or do i have to edit my question?

Comment: It's up to your logic to add what you think it's relevant in `if` statement.